# How to arrange Thumbs with a Line for moving a line in a WPF custom Adorner

Tags: c#, wpf, line, adorner

I am working on a `Adorner` for a `Line` in a drawing program using WPF. The `Line` is drawn in code-behind and then adorned with my custom `Adorner` called `LineAdorner`. I've managed to use a `Thumb` for the start and end point of the `Line`. It's working fine for resizing. My problem is i cant able to move (drag & drop) the line, how to do that?

```
public class ResizingAdorner : Adorner
{
    // Resizing adorner uses Thumbs for visual elements.  
    // The Thumbs have built-in mouse input handling.
    //Thumb topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight;

    private Thumb startThumb;
    private Thumb endThumb;
    private Line selectedLine;
    private Point startPoint;
    private Point endPoint;

    // To store and manage the adorner's visual children.
    VisualCollection visualChildren;
    bool IsControlModeOn = false;
    // Override the VisualChildrenCount and GetVisualChild properties to interface with 
    // the adorner's visual collection.
    protected override int VisualChildrenCount { get { return visualChildren.Count; } }
    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index) { return visualChildren[index]; }

    // Initialize the ResizingAdorner.
    public ResizingAdorner(UIElement adornedElement)
        : base(adornedElement)
    {
        visualChildren = new VisualCollection(this);
        selectedLine = AdornedElement as Line;
        startThumb = new Thumb { Cursor = Cursors.Hand, Width = 8, Height = 8, Background = Brushes.Green };
        endThumb = new Thumb { Cursor = Cursors.Hand, Width = 8, Height = 8, Background = Brushes.BlueViolet };
        startThumb.DragDelta += StartDragDelta;
        endThumb.DragDelta += EndDragDelta;

        startThumb.DragCompleted += new DragCompletedEventHandler(startThumb_DragCompleted);
        endThumb.DragCompleted += new DragCompletedEventHandler(endThumb_DragCompleted);

        visualChildren.Add(startThumb);
        visualChildren.Add(endThumb);
    }


    public event EndDragDeltaEvent endDragDeltaEvent;
    public delegate void EndDragDeltaEvent(object obj, DragCompletedEventArgs e, bool isEnd);

    void startThumb_DragCompleted(object sender, DragCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (endDragDeltaEvent != null)
            endDragDeltaEvent(selectedLine, e, false);
    }

    void endThumb_DragCompleted(object sender, DragCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (endDragDeltaEvent != null)
            endDragDeltaEvent(selectedLine, e, true);
    }

    // Arrange the Adorners.
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        selectedLine = AdornedElement as Line;

        double left = Math.Min(selectedLine.X1, selectedLine.X2);
        double top = Math.Min(selectedLine.Y1, selectedLine.Y2);

        var startRect = new Rect(selectedLine.X1 - (startThumb.Width / 2), selectedLine.Y1 - (startThumb.Width / 2), startThumb.Width, startThumb.Height);
        startThumb.Arrange(startRect);

        var endRect = new Rect(selectedLine.X2 - (endThumb.Width / 2), selectedLine.Y2 - (endThumb.Height / 2), endThumb.Width, endThumb.Height);
        endThumb.Arrange(endRect);

        return finalSize;
    }

    private void StartDragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        Point position = Mouse.GetPosition(this);

        selectedLine.X1 = position.X;
        selectedLine.Y1 = position.Y;
    }

    // Event for the Thumb End Point
    private void EndDragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        Point position = Mouse.GetPosition(this);

        selectedLine.X2 = position.X;
        selectedLine.Y2 = position.Y;
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        if (AdornedElement is Line)
        {
            selectedLine = AdornedElement as Line;
            startPoint = new Point(selectedLine.X1, selectedLine.Y1);
            endPoint = new Point(selectedLine.X2, selectedLine.Y2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to handle the MouseDown, MouseMove and MouseUp events on the line to be able to do that:

Add handlers for those events in the constructor

```
selectedLine.MouseLeftButtonDown += SelectedLineOnMouseLeftButtonDown;
selectedLine.MouseMove += SelectedLineOnMouseMove;
selectedLine.MouseLeftButtonUp += SelectedLineOnMouseLeftButtonUp;
```

And the implementation is something like this

```
private Point origin;

private void SelectedLineOnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) 
{
    e.Handled = true;

    Line line = (Line) sender;
    line.CaptureMouse();

    startPoint = new Point(line.X1, line.Y1);
    endPoint = new Point(line.X2, line.Y2);

    origin = e.GetPosition(line);

    base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
}

private void SelectedLineOnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
{
    base.OnMouseMove(e);
    Line line = (Line) sender;
    if (e.MouseDevice.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed) 
    {
        Point position = e.GetPosition(this);
        e.Handled = true;
        double horizontalDelta = position.X - origin.X;
        double verticalDelta = position.Y - origin.Y;

        line.X1 = startPoint.X + horizontalDelta;
        line.X2 = endPoint.X + horizontalDelta;
        line.Y1 = startPoint.Y + verticalDelta;
        line.Y2 = endPoint.Y + verticalDelta;

        InvalidateArrange();
    }
    else 
    {
        line.ReleaseMouseCapture();
    }
}

private void SelectedLineOnMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) 
{
    Line line = (Line) sender;
    line.ReleaseMouseCapture();
    e.Handled = true;

    base.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(e);
}
```

I also added some InvalidateArrange() calls in the StartDragDelta and EndDragDelta handlers to makes sure the Thumbs move when being dragged.

Comment: Good answer, I need this as well. But when I try this, the line moves too quickly and flies off the canvas. Something isn't right with the `SelectedLineOnMouseMove()` method. I'll have a closer look at this after lunch. Here is a working sample: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6oxjp46vuj443wl/ShapeConnectors%20%282%29.zip?dl=0

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. You are not updating `origin` after moving the line; it only updates when the user first presses the mouse. Add `origin = e.GetPosition(line);` right before the `InvalidateArrange()` line in the `SelectedLineOnMouseMove()` method and you're good. Thanks for this answer.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the problem you're experiencing, but the addition of the line you suggest doesn't make it break on my side either. Glad you found the answer helpful.